# How to render multiple markers at the exact same coordinates in Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, pushpin, overlapping-matches

I have multiple addresses on the same street with the same house number, but with different apartment numbers. Google Maps Geocoding Service (v2) doesn't go down to apartment level accuracy for many addresses and just returned me the exact same geocode coordinates for them.

So the problem is that when I go to display them, only one pushpin shows up no matter how much you zoom in. And my question is; what is a good way to render multiple pushpins at the exact same house address? I've seen how craigslist.org creates a spiral out of the pushpins on their new map feature, but was wondering what my other options are as that seems like a workaround at best.

Ideas?

Comment: Take a look at [markerclusterer](http://sandbox.saeidmohadjer.com/google_map_cluster.php)

Comment: @Dr.Molle I saw that, but that's a zoom thing for clustering. Meaning that from a zoomed out view it combines the clusters, but when you start zooming in, they reslove to different locations. My problem is that I still have one marker if you zoom all the way in.

Comment: when you remove the maxZoom-property, you will still have a cluster and not markers at the same position.

Comment: how about to set cluster radius relate with zoom
if zoom getting close to max zoom the redius should be narrow

Comment: @Dr.Molle - Okay I altered the simple example provided by markerclusterer (which does not have the maxZoom-property defined) using 3 markers on the exact same coordinates and the behavior is not very good for this purpose. It keeps zooming in displaying the group marker all the way down until it reaches the highest zoom level and then if you click it again it disappears leaving just an empty map. Not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Dr.Molle - I was thinking more like a slightly customizable pushpin with a number in it representing the number of matches on that point () which has some built in functionality to handle that last click when its fully zoomed (or possibly your own custom function there).

Comment: all this can be done by using markerclusterer

Comment: @Dr.Molle - after thoroughly using and integrating [markerclustererplus](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus) into my site, I can confidently say that it does not accomodate the scenario above. You can, however, have it show the cluster icon all the way down to the highest zoom level, but that doesn't indicate to the user that there are multiple markers/pins on the exact same location; just that they the markers are close together and grouped by the cluster icon.

Comment: @Dr.Molle - If there is a way, please indicate specifically which configuration option on the [markerclustererplus config page](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html) to do so.

Comment: @Dr.Molle - Hey, thanks for the link to markerclusterer.  It was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: take look at OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier [code](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier), [demo](http://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/demo.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using [Google's dynamic chart icons](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons#plain_pin) which allow you to put a number in the pin identifying that there are multiple markers on this exact some point. Basically, you call their "chart" url with some query params and they give you back your numbered icon which you can then place/set in the existing marker you have on that spot.

```
var markerImage = createMarkerImage(numDuplicates + 1);
existingMarker.setIcon(markerImage);

function createMarkerImage(text)
{
    var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=" + text + "|FF8985|000000",
    new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
    return pinImage;
}
```

**NOTE**: This solution uses a deprecated google API with no end date posted.

> "Important: The Image Charts portion of Google Chart Tools has been
>   officially deprecated as of April 20, 2012. It will continue to work
>   as per our deprecation policy."

**UPDATE:**
I have moved away from the above solution since it's deprecated (and has performance impact for many markers) in leiu of the same end effect of a numbered marker, but using a path of coordinates defining polygon in the shape of a marker along with a `.png` for the marker shadow. Only reason I used my own custom marker is because I needed to create individual markers, each with a unique color (and possibly an embedded number), which the vanilla markers don't support.