# Google map markers overlapping and not visible

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have trouble with my google map script where the markers on a same location overlapped and not visible to user.
I tried to edit my script using OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier available in this link https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier. But overlapping issue exist.No improvement occured.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var geocoder;
    var map;

    // initializing the map
    function initialize()
    {
        // define map center
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.44694705960048,-101.953125);
        // define map options
        var myOptions = 
        {
            zoom: 3,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.MAP,
            scaleControl: true,
            navigationControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
            },
            mapTypeControl: false,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
            }
        };

        // initialize map
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        // add event listener for when a user clicks on the map
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
            findAddress(event.latLng);
        });
    }

    // finds the address for the given location
    function findAddress(loc)
    {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 

        if (geocoder) 
        {
            geocoder.geocode({'latLng': loc}, function(results, status) 
            {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
                {
                    if (results[0]) 
                    {
                        address = results[0].formatted_address;

                        // fill in the results in the form
                        document.getElementById('lat').value = loc.lat();
                        document.getElementById('long').value = loc.lng();
                        document.getElementById('address').value = address;
                    }
                } 
                else 
                {
                    alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // initialize the array of markers
    var markers = new Array();

    // the function that adds the markers to the map
    function addMarkers()
    {
        // get the values for the markers from the hidden elements in the form
        var lats = document.getElementById('lats').value;
        var lngs = document.getElementById('lngs').value;
        var addresses = document.getElementById('addresses').value;
        var names = document.getElementById('names').value;
        var descrs = document.getElementById('descrs').value;
        var photos = document.getElementById('photos').value;
        var user_names = document.getElementById('user_names').value;
        var user_locs = document.getElementById('user_locs').value;

        var las = lats.split(";;")
        var lgs = lngs.split(";;")
        var ads = addresses.split(";;")
        var nms = names.split(";;")
        var dss = descrs.split(";;")
        var phs = photos.split(";;")
        var usrn = user_names.split(";;")
        var usrl = user_locs.split(";;")

        // for every location, create a new marker and infowindow for it
        for (i=0; i<las.length; i++)
        {
            if (las[i] != "")
            {
                // add marker
                var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(las[i],lgs[i]);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: loc, 
                    map: window.map,
                    title: nms[i]
                });

                markers[i] = marker;

                var contentString = [
                  '<div id="tabs">',
                   '<div id="tab-1">',
                    '<p><span>'+nms[i]+'</span></p>',
                    '<p><img src="./photos/'+phs[i]+'"/></p>'+
                  '</div>',
                    '<div id="tab-3">',
                    '<p><a href="trainer-profile.php?id='+usrn[i]+'"><img src="images/b-line.jpg"/></a></p>',
                  '</div>',
                  '</div>'
                ].join('');

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

                bindInfoWindow(marker, window.map, infowindow, contentString);
            }
        }
    }

    // make conection between infowindow and marker (the infowindw shows up when the user goes with the mouse over the marker)
    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, contentString)
    {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {

            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

            infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            $("#tabs").tabs();
         });
    }

    // highlighting a marker
        // make the marker show on top of the others
        // change the selected markers icon
    function highlightMarker(index)
    {
        // change zindex and icon
        for (i=0; i<markers.length; i++)
        {
            if (i == index)
            {
                markers[i].setZIndex(10);
                markers[i].setIcon('http://www.google.com/mapfiles/arrow.png');
            }
            else
            {
                markers[i].setZIndex(2);
                markers[i].setIcon('http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png');
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the issue, what does "But unable to rectify my issue" mean? Do you get javascript errors?  Are you including the OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier script (it doesn't appear in your question)?  Are you using the OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier script?

Comment: I have no javascript errors.but my markers on google map are overlapped.So i cant see some markers.

Comment: I tried to edit my script for OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.But no improvement occured.still overlapping exists

Comment: We cannot see/reproduce that because information about markers locations/data is missing. Additionally, in function `bindInfoWindow()` you have pretty annoying event listener which produce that center is changing if you move mouse around.

Comment: The markers are shown by getting zip codes and converted them to longitudes and latitudes.They are shown as marker on map. Since two persons are from same zip register, there occur two markers and one google map marker is overlapping with another. is there any way we can show that two markers simultaneously..

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a jsfiddle which demonstrates the issue and your attempt to fix it using OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier.

Answer (score 1):

Refer [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248365/)

Comment: In the post itself i explained OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier not working